# Ext JS-Restrict to manual CellEditing only.

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am using cell editing for a grid in Ext JS. I want to edit the cell by manually calling the startEdit method, rather than through clicks. How can I disable editor from being editable through clicks. I have a check column which will only allow editing of a particular column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually modified the beforeedit listener of cell editor and it worked.